# ZSH takes two tabs to complete filenames

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I love Zsh's tab completions, but it's frustrating when there is only one possible option and I have to tab twice to tab complete the filename.

For example, if this is a list of files in a directory:

```
- a.txt
- b.txt
- x.txt
```

and I type `cat x<TAB>` in ZSH, I get this at the prompt:

```
$ cat x
x.txt
```

I have to TAB again to get the value. What can I do to get ZSH to complete the filename with only the first tab?

Here's my setopt:

```
alwaystoend
autocd
autonamedirs
autopushd
cdablevars
completeinword
correctall
extendedhistory
noflowcontrol
histexpiredupsfirst
histignoredups
histignorespace
histverify
incappendhistory
interactive
longlistjobs
menucomplete
monitor
promptsubst
pushdignoredups
sharehistory
shinstdin
zle
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setting I needed to fix was

```
zstyle '*' single-ignored show
```

in the `completion.zsh` file in oh-my-zsh. I changed it to

```
zstyle '*' single-ignored complete
```